# The duration of OutputCache ASP.NET MVC 2 does not work properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I attach a OutputCache to an action method with following profile where the **duration** is of 12 hours.

```
<add name="DefaultProfile"      enabled ="true" noStore="false" duration="43200" varyByCustom="pq" varyByParam="none" location="Any"/>
```

The **problem** is server-side cache expires after just 2 or 3 minutes, not 12 hours as specified.

What setting I was missing out so that the cache mechanisms fail to conform to the specified duration.

Comment: Does all web application behave so or just this particular one ? And when you leave just the duration, what is happening then ?

Comment: @Martin: all the application behave so.